# How to get all the unicodes for \p{L} in Java Script

Tags: javascript, regex, localization

I am having a regular expression `/([\w]+)\s*$/`

It (\w) recognizes only English characters. But i also want to recognize non English characters or any letter from any language. I have seen in PHP using `\p{L}` which does the same functionality.

But `\p{L}` is not being supported by JS. So i want to use all Unicodes the `\p{L}` using to use it in place of `\w` in my regex, so that it matches all characters from all languages.

Any reference where to get this from.

Edit: I dont want to use any libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by "all characters from all languages"? Can you give an example of a character that _wouldn't_ be included?

Comment: \w  dont contain non english character like ü,ä etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you trying to say that you don't want to match `ü`? How is that not a character?

Comment: I want to match those characters also. I want to have a regex which works same as \p{L} in PHP

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew is there any solution with out using any libraries